# Como faço para validar entrada em c?

Tags: c, scanf

O meu problema é que tenho que forçar o usuário a entrar com um valor somente inteiro, caso ele coloque qualquer outra coisa (caracteres ou decimais) eu devo fazer com que ele digite novamente. Já tentei fazer uma validação pelo `scanf` mas não deu certo. Então eu fiz uma função pra fazer a validação, mas não deu certo,então tirei a funçãoe deixei tudo na `main`mesmo e também não esta dando certo, não tenho mais ideias...

Assim esta o código agora, o programa acusa qualquer entrada como invalida, mesmo se for um numero inteiro.

```
int maiorNumero(int,int);

int main()
{
    int a=0,b=0;
    int flag=0,maior=0;

do
{
    fflush(stdin);
    puts("Digite um numero inteiro:\n");
    scanf("%i",&a);
    puts("Digite um numero inteiro:\n");
    scanf("%i",&b);

    float f=a;
    float f2=b;
    char c=a;
    char c2=b;

    if(f!=a || f2!=b || c!=a || c2!=b)
    {
        flag=1;
        puts("Numero invalido!\nDigite apenas NUMEROS INTEIROS.\n");
    }
    else
    flag=0;

}while(flag==1);

maior=maiorNumero(a,b);
printf("O maior numero digitado foi: %i .",maior);

return 0;
}


int maiorNumero(int a, int b)
{
   int maior;

   if(a>b)
   {
      maior=a;
   }
   else
   if(a<b)
    {
        maior=b;
    }

return maior;
}
```

O que estou errando? E se o numero de variaveis (que é 2:`a` `b`) for `n` onde `n` é definido pelo usuário, vou poder usar essa logica ou terei que usar validação pelo `scanf`?

Answer (score 1):

O melhor caminho para seguir é analisar a entrada a partir de uma String (ou vetor de caracteres), pois assim podemos decidir o que é ou não inteiro. É importante dizer que o C, para definir os caracteres, usa a [Tabela ASCII](http://ic.unicamp.br/~everton/aulas/hardware/tabelaASCII.pdf), ou seja, todo caractere tem um valor inteiro e vice-versa. Vemos na tabela que o primeiro número é o '0' e que o último é o '9', logo se o valor que o usuário digitou for menor que '0' ou maior que '9', sabemos que não é um número. Reparamos também, que os valores na Tabela estam em ordem crescente, ou seja, se '0' = 48, '1' = 48+1 = 49, '5' = 48 + 5 = 53 e assim por diante. Tendo isso em mente, podemos converter de caractere para inteiro. Fiz uma função bem simples que retorna NULL caso a sua entrada contenha algo diferente de números:

```
int inteiro_validado(){
//Buffer para entrada da variável
char buffer[100];
//Ponteiro com endereco da String
char * entrada = gets(buffer);fflush(stdin); 
int i, resultado = 0, teste;
//Fazemos um loop para checar caractere por caractere da entrada
for(i = 0; i < strlen(entrada); i++){
    //Checa se é um numero
    if(entrada[i] >= '0' && entrada[i] <= '9'){
        //Se for, reduz da tabela ASCII
        teste = entrada[i] - '0';
        //Essa soma apenas coloca na casa decimal certa, se for 1024, ele vai fazer 1000 + 20 + 4
        resultado += teste * pow(10, strlen(entrada) - i - 1);
    }else{
        //A entrada contem um valor nao numérico
        return NULL;
    }
}

return resultado;
```

}

Para aplicar este código é  bem simples, basta :`int i = inteiro_validado()` e checar se `i = NULL`, se for, sua entrada contém caracteres não-numéricos.

Outra dica é não usar `%i` para entrada de inteiros, pois `%i` permite a entrada de valores em outras bases suportadas pelo C, como a hexadecimal e a octal. Use `%d` para bases decimais, `%o` para octais e `%x` para hexadecimais

Answer (score 0):

Quando tenta acrescentar um valor *String* em um *Integer*, dará erro de memória(Normalmente).

Mas se ler uma *String* isso é possível. Ao invés de usar o `scanf("%i")` e usar `scanf("%s")`, pode usar o método `atoi` para converter o valor em inteiro (retorna **0** se não for um número).

Ou então verificar os caracteres dentro da *String*.

```
int x;
flag = 0;
for(x=0; x<strlen(a); x++){
    if(a[x] < '0' || a[x] > '9'){
        flag = 1;
        break;
    }
}
// O mesmo deve ser feito para b
```